# Reduce the JSON Response in Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I have this type of  `JSON` also apply filter

```
"apps": [
            {
                "id": 78,
                "createdAt": "05-26-2021 08:53:00",
                "title": "Testing App 51",
                "updatedAt": "05-26-2021 08:53:32",
                "organizationId": 1,
    }]
```

but I want to apply `short`, `medium`, and `long` in which different type of JSON response I want.
e.g: In `short` i just need `id` and `title` in JSON .
I used `generic specification` in which I pass entity object and it returns whole entity as JSON response.

Comment: This question is very unclear to me. But it sounds like something that Json views can solve? https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation

Comment: @Gimby what was unclear Kindly elaborate ?

Comment: No code, just a vague high level description. I also have no idea what a "generic specification" is.

Comment: @Gimby I am facing the problem that my entity's JSON response is too big e.g. I have around 25 columns but I need only a few in JSON Response so I want to create three queries i.e Short in which I want to get Four Column than in medium I am looking for 12 columns and In ` long` I am looking for 18 columns but at the moment I am stuck. If you have any solution or any link where I can get some knowledge about this would be really helpful. Thanks !!

Comment: How about the link I provided in my first comment?

Comment: @Gimby Sorry! it's not helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the combination of `SimpleBeanPropertyFilter` + `FilterProvider` + `MappingJacksonValue`. It helps you to ignore fields dinamically while serializing an object to JSON.

```java
// set the filter ID "appFilter"
@JsonFilter("appFilter")
public class App {
  private Integer id;
  private String title;
  private Integer organizationId;
  ... getter / setter ...
}

// In the controller,
@GetMapping("/app/{id}")
public MappingJacksonValue getApp(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
  // make a json except the key "organizationId:
  SimpleBeanPropertyFilter sbpf = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept("organizationId");
  // make a filter provider
  FilterProvider fp = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("appFilter", sbpf);
  // fetch an app data
  App app = appService.getApp(id);
  // apply the filter provider for the instance of App.
  MappingJacksonValue mjv = new MappingJacksonValue(app);
  mappingJacksonValue.setFilters(filterProvider);
  return mjv;
}
```

Hope you have a hint. I found that code [here](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-dynamically-ignore-fields-while-serial).

Happy Coding!